# how to use q promises?

Tags: node.js, q

I have two mongoose models that control mongo actions for each model. from an index route I am calling a function from one of my models I want to call a function from my other model when the first one finishes.
Assume the following:

```
ThingOneSchema = new Schema({ _id :String, name :String});
ThingOneSchema.statics.saveUser = function(thing, callback){
  ...do some stuff

ThingTwoSchema = new Schema({_id :String, property:String});
ThingTwoSchema.statics.doSomething = function(prop, callback){
  ... do some stuff
```

In my calls from index I would like to call doSomething from thingTwoSchema and then saveUser from ThingOneSchema. I find Q kinda confusing when trying to apply it in my program. Often examples take the form of `doSomething(result).then(function(result))`
but I faile to see how q is invoked this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to chain the promises as following

```
doSomething(res).then(function callback(res) {
  //some stuff again
})
```

Make sure function `doSomething` return a promise.

```
function doSomething (res) {
   //do stuff..
   return Q(some_result);
}
```

Then, your `callback` which passed to `then` will be called with arguments `some_result` later on.

If your async operations are callback based instead of promise based, make sure you have checked out [deferred](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds). It allows you to wrap those async calls with Q promise.

Here is another bunch of [examples](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Examples-Gallery) which captures common problems when dealing with promise.